# Why does ruby class comparison fail in this case statement?

Tags: ruby, switch-statement

Given the following rspec example, why is `when Question` not truthy?

```
require "rails_helper"
class Question
end

describe Question do
  it "confuses me" do
    klass = Question

    # this passes
    expect(klass).to eq(Question)

    # this doesn't fail (thankfully)
    fail "loudly" if klass != Question

    case klass
    when Question # this doesn't match ???
      tada = ""
      expect(tada).to eq("")
    else
      # why?????
      fail "into confusion"
    end
  end
end
```

And no this isn't a course assignment lol. I ran into this at work and now I don't know what's true anymore.

side note, using string comparison works:

```
require "rails_helper"
class Question
end

describe Question do
  it "confuses me" do
    klass = Question

    # this passes
    expect(klass).to eq(Question)

    # this doesn't fail (thankfully)
    fail "loudly" if klass != Question

    case klass.to_s
    when Question.to_s # this doesn't match ???
      tada = ""
      expect(tada).to eq("")
    else
      # why?????
      fail "into confusion"
    end
  end
end
```

another aside: using rspec was a convenient way to test this unexpected behavior. this issue isn't related to rspec.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you are mixing up *classes* and *instances*.

Normally when you use a class in a `when` clause inside a `case` statement, you are testing whether the variable is an *instance* of that class:

```
obj = Question.new # Note the 'new' here

case obj
when Question
  # obj is an instance of Question, so this will match.
  puts "matches Question"

when SomethingElse
  # instances of SomethingElse would match here.
  puts "matches Something else"
end

# => Outputs "matches Question"
```

In your example, you aren’t testing an instance of `Question`, but rather `Question` itself, which is a class and therefore an instance of `Class`:

```
klass = Question  # No 'new', just Question itself.

case klass
when Question
  # klass isn't an instance of Question, so this doesn't match...
  puts "matches Question"

when Class
  # klass actually is Question, which is an instance of Class,
  # so this does match.
  puts "matches Class"

end

# => Outputs "matches Class".
```

This works because of how [`Module.===` is defined](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.2/Module.html#method-i-3D-3D-3D) (`Class` is a subclass of `Module`):

> `mod === obj → true or false`
>
> Case Equality—Returns `true` if *obj* is an instance of `mod` or an instance of one of `mod`’s descendants. Of limited use for modules, but can be used in `case` statements to classify objects by class.

With `String`s, `===` is an alias of `==`, so `when` clauses will match on equality.

Answer (score -1):

Update: the original solution I posted worked because of the string comparison, but was implementing `===` on the instance and not on the class. I removed the `.to_s` and converted `===` into `self.===` and now the example solution below works for me they way I expect.

Corrected Original:
I just learned that if I want to compare two classes, they both will need to implement `self.===`. Here's a working example:

```
require "rails_helper"
class Question
  def self.===(other)
    other == self
  end
end

describe Question do
  it "confuses me" do
    klass = Question

    # this passes
    expect(klass).to eq(Question)

    # this doesn't fail (thankfully)
    fail "loudly" if klass != Question

    case klass
    when Question
      tada = ""
      expect(tada).to eq("")
    else
      fail "fail? it'll never fail :) "
    end
  end
end
```

And here's the article that helped me find that answer:
https://thoughtbot.com/blog/case-equality-operator-in-ruby

Comment: *side note, using string comparison works*